# VS2008 Unit tests failed when you select Test- Debug- All Tests in Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging

in Debug mode the tests which throw a custom exception give an error message like

```
Exception of type 'CustomProductException' was thrown instead of 'CustomProductException'
```

Fail.But when I choose Test - **Run** - All Tests in Solution rather than Debug, all Tests pass.Why is this happening? Any pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen before.  I believe the issue was my references.  Clean your entire solution, and delete every reference in every project in your solution to the assembly that contains CustomProductException.

Next, re-add your references, making sure to reference the project that compiles the assembly, not the compiled assembly on disk.